# How do I attach files to nodes?

Tags: files, 8

I need to add files to multiple value file field using drupal rest api (restws module).
return format of restws is something like this :

```
"field_files": [

    {
        "file": {
            "uri": "http://drupal/file/445",
            "id": "445",
            "resource": "file"
        }
    }
],
```

but when I send it to `http//drupal/node/<node_id>` restws returns not acceptable.

Can anyone suggest which format I must use to send data to?

and second question : How can I upload files using restws module ?

Comment: Never tried restws module but you can try to json_encode your string and try to add .json to the URL ...

Comment: I've worked with drupal services module without problems, but for some reasons I've switched to restws, I can edit a node with one file but solution not working when node have more than one file.

Answer (score 1):

For my first question:
I'm sending data with this format and it works now

```
{
  "field_files":[

    { 
      "fid": "445"
    },

    {
      "fid":"446"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where *fid* is the *id* of an existing and accessible file.

For my second question, I've written module extending *restws classes* that user can submit data like the way user submits for [services](https://drupal.org/project/services) rest api.

Idea behind my module is that user submits data and module checks validation data and if data is valid saves file using drupal [file_save_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_data/7) function.